Time in ADM-ZIP for NodeJS
I am using adm-zip in NodeJS but my files in compressed packages have always got the timestamp of zip creation. I would like that files keep the original date and hour, not
the moment when I create the zip. Which option should I apply to zip.addFile(...) ?
I checked the source but I don't understand how it sets the attributes.
Thanks.
zip.addFile(filename, content, comment, date) doesn't work
